# FORTRAN 77 Simple input/out

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am new to FORTRAN, and must write a FORTRAN 77 program to read the following format from a file redirection or standard input:

```
[CHARACTER] [REAL] [REAL] [REAL] ... (can have any number of these)
D [INTEGER] (only one of these)
[REAL] [REAL] [REAL] ... (can have any number of these)
```

example input could be:

```
T 1.0 2.0 3.0
S 1.0 2.0 4.0
Y 3.0 4.0 5.0
D 2
3.0 5.0 6.0
4.5 4.6 5.6
```

My *native* language is C++, so I'm new to this whole idea of a read statement going to the next line automatically.

So far, I have the following code:

```
c234567
      character*1 D
      character*1 LETTER
      real X, Y, Z
      integer lines
      real point1, point2, point3
```

85     format (3F10.6)
100    format (A1, 5X, F10.6, 5X, F10.6, 4X, F10.6)
990    format (A, I10)

```
      MAX = 6
      LETTER = 'Z'
      D = 'D'

      read *, LETTER, X, Y, Z
```

10     if(LETTER .ne. D) then
           write (6, 100) LETTER, X, Y, Z
           read *, LETTER, X, Y, Z
           goto 10
        else 
           goto 20
        endif

C =====================================================
20      lines = aint(X)
        write (*,990) 'LINES: ', lines
        write (6, 85) X, Y, Z
        read *, Z
        write (6, 85) X, Y, Z
        end

As you can see, I get the first portion of the input fine, but after that it kind of all goes to mush because of the read statement: read*, Z going to the next line. In my specific input file provided above, I get the 2 after the D, and the next two values (3.0, 5.0) but I skip the 6.0

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can the initial three real lines have `D` as their leading character? If not the parsing is pretty easy.

Comment: No they can't. Where am I going wrong then?

Comment: Is definitely only F77 allowed? Fortran 90 has way more features for string operations.  It's not about the fixed format (F90 can use that too), but only about the compiler you use.  Most compilers out there (gfortran, ifort, ...) are Fortran 90/95 compilers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must compile using fort77.

Comment: @john : only an idiot imposes the use of f77 today. Change job. You are ruining your career and expertise.

Comment: Besides Fortran 90 having better string IO, Fortran 2003 has stream IO, which allows reading files without imposing a record structure.  So if there wasn't the insistence on FORTRAN 77, you could read the file one character at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that your lines will never exceed a maximum length, I suggest to read the whole line and then to parse the line according to your rules.

An example using a maximum line length of 1024 characters:

```
       CHARACTER*1024 line
       CHARACTER letter
100    FORMAT (A)
       READ(*,100) line
       READ(line, *) letter
       IF (letter .eq. 'T') THEN
          ...
       END IF
```

Maybe this technique works for you.

Comment: I have thought about that too, but the line can be any length. I doubt there would ever be one of over 1024 chars, but I need it to work in that case, either way.

Comment: john, I was never aware of a absolutely unlimited way to read lines in fortran 77. Even using a implied loop is limited by the size of the receiving array.

Comment: @john It's an interesting problem and I am not even sure if it is solvable without further implications.  If it is on a UNIX system, maybe you can open "/dev/stdin" on a different unit number using form='binary' and then parse the input byte by byte.  Maybe [this link](http://geospatialmethods.org/documents/fortranio.html) can help you.  Unfortunately, I have to leave now - even though I would like to see the solution.

Comment: This is best solution to have highly flexible input-controlled processing in Fortran.   The mixed character and numeric data with unknown number of numeric items per line after the character is tough otherwise.  Another way is to pre-scan the file and to use "rewind". I think that you are best off figuring out a maximum possible line length, adding margin to the length, and using this method.  P.S.  The requirement to use FORTRAN 77 is peculiar ... Fortran 90 has been around for two decades ... why are some people hanging on?

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses. It's better knowing that it's nearly impossible without adding something else, then sitting here and trying to figure out a way. Does anyone know how to reset the stream pointer? I'm guessing that's not possible.

Comment: I'd go with this route as well.  And if the number of values are totally unknown and it goes like millions of character, i'd consider pre-process the text file with some language you know...

Comment: I like that idea, yosukesabai. I think I'll pre-process in Bash or C++.

Comment: The info on Fortran Binary I/O at http://geospatialmethods.org/documents/fortranio.html, referred to above, is obsolete.  Access="direct" shouldn't be used unless you actually need direct access.  For sequential, non-record based access, use access="stream" -- part of Fortran 2003 and widely available.

Comment: @m-s-b I only suggested the "binary" access because it works with fort77 (as was asked for), not because it is my preferred way...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't even looked at you code but I would suggest a strategy like this

```
(1) read the initial character of the line
if not "D" then 
    read reals
    store the line
    loop to (1)
else
    read one integer
    store the line
    break
endif
read lines of reals until end-of-file
```

My fortran is *very* rusty, but I believe that there are constructs that will help you with this. Certainly the `END` modifier to `READ` is going to be helpful with the last bit.

---

After a little experimenting, I find that `gfortran` seems to support the old trailing `$` for non-advancing input convention *and* `advance='no'`. However, `g77` *does not*. I can't speak to any other compiler--as far as I know this was never standardized until fortran 90 where `advance='no'` was introduced.

Demo code that works in `gfortran`, but not in `g77`

```
      program temp
c234567
      character a
      integer i
      real x, y, z, w(50)

c This or with (*,'(A1 $)')
      read (*,'(A1)',advance='no') a

      if (a .eq. 'D') then
         read (*,*) i
         write (*,*) a, i
      endif

      end
```

This should be enough to make the incremental strategy work *if* you compiler supports non-advancing input somehow.

The alternative is to read the letter plus the rest of the line into a large character buffer, then parse the buffer separately along the lines of

```
      character a, buf(1024)
      read (*,'(a1, a1024)') a, buf
      if (a .eq. d) then
         read (buf,*) i
      endif
```

Comment: Right. That is the strategy I tried originally. When you read the initial character of the line, it automatically goes to the next line. Like in my sample input file, if you read the "T", it goes right to the next line. so when you read the reals, you will get the reals from the "S" line.

Comment: Also, I am not reading from a file, but I am redirecting from a file. I don't think END will help me here.